# What may change when I work on a platform like Slader?

Tags: tex-general

I just started using LaTeX 2 weeks ago on a website called Slader. The website provides a platform on which you can upload your answers to many textbooks problems.
However, I wonder if learning LaTeX in general will help me to improve my answers there.
Thank you

Comment: I suspect this is off topic as there isn't really any tex question here. (The premise of a site posting answers to textbook questions seems very dubious as well, but that's another issue)